# Notice: Undefined index: id in c:\program files (x86)\easyphp1-8\www\new folder\edit.php on line 33

Tags: php

here is my code.. i don't know what the problem is.. after click submit button..the error come.. stuck for a whole day

```
<?

if (isset($_GET['do']) && $_GET['do'] == 'update')
{
$id=$_POST["id"];
$name=$_POST["name"];
$address=$_POST["address"];
$contact=$_POST["contact"];
$item=$_POST["item"];
$query="update itemorder set name='$name',address='$address',contact='$contact',item='$item' where id=$id";
mysql_query($query);

    echo "<center>Successfully Updated in DATABASE</center>";
    include("search.php");

}
?>
<center>
  <h1><u>Student Database</u></h1>
</center>
<?
$id=$_GET["id"]; //the problem here, line 33
$query="select * from itemorder where id='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($query);
         while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

?>
```

the rest of my source code is below... you can this

```
<form name="update" method="post" action="edit.php">
  <table style=" border:1px solid silver" cellpadding="5px" cellspacing="0px" align="center" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4" style="background:#0066FF; color:#FFFFFF; font-size:20px">ADD STUDENT RECORD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Enter ID</td>
      <td><? echo $row[0];?>
        <input name="id" type="hidden" id="id" value="<? echo $row[0];?>" size="20"></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
```

and this...i dont know where the problem

```
<tr>
      <td>Enter Name</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="name" size="20" value="<? echo $row[2];?>"></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Address</td>
      <td><input name="address" type="text" id="address" value="<? echo $row[3];?>" size="20"></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Contact</td>
      <td><input name="contact" type="text" id="contact" value="<? echo $row[4];?>" size="20"></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Enter Item</td>
      <td><input name="item" type="text" disabled="disabled" id="item" value="<? echo $row[1];?>" size="20"></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4" align="center"><input type="hidden" name="do" value="update">
        <input type="submit" value="UPDATE RECORD"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
<?  ?>
<p align="center"><a href="index.php">Go Back to Home</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check that your using `$_POST` and `$_GET`, Please use either GET OR POST  but not both , Your `id` is not set,  Your URL dosnot have `?id=25` , Use `isset(isset($_GET["id"]))` to avoid this error

or you can simply use `$_REQUEST['id']` to get the id data

```
<?
if(isset($_GET["id"])){    
$id=$_GET["id"]; //the problem here, line 33    
$query="select * from itemorder where id='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($query);
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
         // fetch records
}else{
echo  "no records found with the id $id";
}
?>
```

Comment: i already use $_REQUEST['id'] but the error come again at the next line..line 34

Comment: Does URL have `?id=12` as extention ?

Comment: i'm sorry, im new to php.. so how to put the ?id=12 as extension?

Comment: how to put it? something like this?
<? 
 isset(isset($_GET["id"]))
 $query="select * from itemorder where id='$id'"; 
 $result=mysql_query($query); 
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { }  ?>

Comment: look i changed my answer. do something like that

Comment: Think stakoverflow doesnot allow that

Comment: Edit the whole question and put your source in it

Comment: yeah you can check it now

Comment: change the action of the page `<form name="update" method="post" action="edit.php?id=<? echo $row[0];?>">`

Comment: how i put the isset(isset($_GET["id"])) ? need semicolon at the end? still marking red in my dreamweaver..

Comment: you look properly into my answer, you will find it

Comment: `<?
if(isset($_GET["id"])){    
$id=$_GET["id"]; //the problem here, line 33    
$query="select * from itemorder where id='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($query);
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
         // fetch records
}else{
echo  "no records found with the id $id";
}
?>`

Comment: if it helped, please consider marking my answer as the accepted solution by clicking on the green checkmark http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Comment: change the action of the page `<form name="update" method="post" action="edit.php?id=<? echo $row[0];?>">`

Answer (score 0):

You missed a brace

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
} //<--- here
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
   if(isset($_GET["id"]))
   {
       $id=$_GET["id"];
   }
   else
   { 
       $id=0;
   }
```

You have to define default value if not set. OR you can define select query in if condition.

Comment: hi sir, i also use your solution, but the error come out again.. at this line
$query="select * from itemorder where id='$id'";

Comment: i try this, how is that sir?
<?
 if(isset($_GET["id"]))
   {
       $id=$_GET["id"];
   }
$query="select * from itemorder where id='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($query);
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   
}
?>

Comment: If your `$id` set or not but the query always executes ,so it always gives you error.for that try `<? if(isset($_GET["id"])) { $id=$_GET["id"];  $query="select * from itemorder where id='$id'"; $result=mysql_query($query); while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { }  }  ?>`

Comment: Yes ,this is what i want to tell you. Because `$id` is not set then no query is executed and no error.